# setText for edittext causing crash in addTextChangedListener

Tags: android, android-edittext

Im trying to strip all non standard letter characters from an edittext textbox on an android app im making.   I am successfully creating a listener, obtaining the value and removing bad chrs via a regex.  however, the .setText line below causes the app to crash.   Anyone got any ideas how to get around this and dynamically mask certain chrs?

```
filenameTextBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() { 

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        FILENAME=s.toString();
        FILENAME = FILENAME.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "");
        filenameTextBox.setText(FILENAME);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hope this snippet will help you if i understand your problem clearly

```
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable)
        {
            if (editable.length() != 0)
            {
                chatTextArea.removeTextChangedListener(this);
                chatTextArea.setText("your text");
                chatTextArea.addTextChangedListener(this);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you creating an infinite loop? You can log each time the handler is called and see how many times it's called.

Comment: Goto; you genius! Thanks, that was an important lesson in remembering to use debug.

Comment: however, how do i resolve this? I dont know what method I can use to force an update of the text if i find i want to correct it as its typed.  The problem also occurs on afterTextChanged method.

Comment: Use a class boolean variable to check if the method is already running. Check if it is true at the begining of the method: if not, set it to true and do the job. Don't forget to set it to false at the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
    {
        chatTextArea.removeTextChangedListener(this);
        String s_new = s.toString().replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""); // for example, if need
        chatTextArea.setText(s_new);
        chatTextArea.setSelection(start + count + s_new.length() - s.length());
        chatTextArea.addTextChangedListener(this);
    }
```